# Power BI => Security - share only certain Rows AND certain Tabs with users

Tags: security, powerbi

I am learning to use power bi. I have pubblished my dashboard in the company workspace and I would like to set the security level as follow:

I would like to have users to see a subset of the tabs.

Steps:

1. Created measure => User Logged in = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
2. Created an access table: With emails and related page they have acces to Eg.

| USER | Pages |
| --- | --- |
| ABC@hotmail.com | Page1 |
| DEF@hotmail.com | Page2 |

Where Page1 and Page2 are The names of the tabs of my dashboards

3. manage Roles => [User] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
4. I shared the dashboard with users.

Users can open the dashboard and see the tabs but the cannot see the content.

Is this the best way of doing it, am i missing som steps or there is a better way?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to separate your Dataset from your reports.  Then you can have two separate reports based on the same Dataset, and can secure them separately.

See [Connect to datasets in the Power BI service from Power BI Desktop](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-report-lifecycle-datasets)

So you have one .pbix file with your Dataset and some report pages for testing and development purposes.  And two other .pbix files for the two reports.